# TCP Messages are fragmented (split) in Win7 if datasize is more than 1074 bytes

Tags: tcp, message

I have used simple Socket class from .NET framework to send and receive data messages through TCP. When I run my tcp client app on Windows XP, then the data message is not fragmented (split). But when I run same tcp client app on Windows 7, the data messages are fragmented (split) when the data message size is more than 1074 bytes.

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint("<server ip address>", 601); 
Socket tcpSocket = new Socket(ipEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
tcpSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint.Address, ipEndPoint.Port);
tcpSocket .Send(data, data.Length, 0);
tcpSocket.Close();
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you send more data ? Send something like 1M, see if it keeps splitting.

Comment: Does this happen on the same network ?

Answer (score 3):

A TCP connection is a stream of bytes, it knows nothing of your message boundaries.

Any single read from a TCP connection can (and will) return between 1 byte and the size of the buffer supplied. This may change due to network conditions.

There is NO relationship between the amount of data written to a TCP connection by a particular call to Send() and the amount of data read from a connection by a call to Recv(),, except that all of the data written will be returned by a series of Recv calls.

You should always loop to receive data and use your own message framing to determine your message boundaries.

I wrote more about this here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/testingsocketservers.aspx back in 2002.